# How to display information?

Tags: c, gstreamer

sorry for the previous post. I'll try to be more precise.

Using Gstreamer I created a pipeline, which contains an element of video.ts, I can see and hear the video without problems, but I would like to get some information packages video.ts.

The information is to be interested get me PTS, DTS, OFFSET and PID. To view these values I used the property of "emit-stats" of Tsdemux.

> g_object_set(G_OBJECT(v1_demux),"emit-stats",1,NULL);

Now, I want to see the values of PTS, DTS, OFFSET and PID. To do this use "gst_bus_add_watch" and create several cases for messages

```
case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print (" \n");
        g_print (" End of video\n");

        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
    break;

case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
        gchar *debug;
        GError *error;

        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);

        g_free (debug);
        g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free (error);

        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
        break;
}/*end case error*/

case GST_MESSAGE_ELEMENT:{

    if(strcmp(GST_MESSAGE_SRC_NAME (msg),"mux")==0){
        msg_struct=gst_message_get_structure(msg);

       i=i+1;
       g_print ("Element nº: %d \n", i);

       /* get PID,PTS,DTS,OFFSET value */
       pts =gst_structure_get_value (msg_struct,"pts");
       dts =gst_structure_get_value (msg_struct,"dts");
       offset =gst_structure_get_value (msg_struct,"offset");
       pid =gst_structure_get_value (msg_struct,"pid");

       /*display information PTS, DTS, OFFSET*/
       if(pts!=0){
           g_print(" *PID= % " G_GUINT64_FORMAT" *PTS= % " G_GUINT64_FORMAT " *Offset: % " G_GUINT64_FORMAT "\n",g_value_get_uint64(pid), g_value_get_uint64(pts),g_value_get_uint64(offset));
       }else if (dts!=0){
           g_print(" *DTS= % " G_GUINT64_FORMAT " *Offset: % " G_GUINT64_FORMAT "\n",g_value_get_uint64(dts),g_value_get_uint64(offset));
       }else if (pts==0 && dts==0){
           g_print(" *Paquete nulo: PTS=0 DTS=0 \n" );
       }
    }
```

Now I can see the values of PTS, DTS and OFFSET. This part could be solve whit lot of patience, test and correct errors. But the PID is not displayed correctly and I do not really know how to solve this.

show a snapshot of messages

> estoy imprimiendo estados n?: 490 
>    *DTS= 4672782274 *Offset: 12554828
>   Element n?: 491
>
> (test:3385): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint64: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT64 (value)' failed
>    *PID= 0 *PTS= 4672793074 *Offset: 12554828
>   Element n?: 492
>
> (test:3385): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint64: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT64 (value)' failed
>    *PID= 0 *PTS= 4672746274 *Offset: 12556520
>   Element n?: 493
>
> (test:3385): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_uint64: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_UINT64 (value)' failed
>    *PID= 0 *PTS= 4672748074 *Offset: 12605024
>   Element n?: 494

What I can do, to show me the PID correctly?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a code sample of what you've attempted.

Answer (score 1):

A GstStructure is a collection of key/value pairs. You can use

```
gchar * gst_structure_to_string (const GstStructure *structure);
```

to display all fields. In you case

```
g_print("%s\n", gst_structure_to_string(gst_message_get_structure(msg)));
```